# Google trends api results in java

Tags: java, oop, object

I am using Google trends to get trends for particulate keyword. it will returning JSON but main problem is that i want to create class that holds data and used in java code as array List. 
I am confused what is the class structure for it when i get result look like below

```
{"version":"0.6","status":"ok","sig":"1248242565",
 "table":
    { "cols":  
       [{"id":"date","label":"Date","type":"date","pattern":""}, 
        {"id":"query0","label":"linkedin","type":"number","pattern":""},
        {"id":"query1","label":"facebook","type":"number","pattern":""}],

       "rows":[{"c":[{"v":new Date(2004,0,1),"f":"January 2004"},{"v":0.0,"f":"0"},{"v":0.0,"f":"0"}]},
               {"c":[{"v":new Date(2004,5,1),"f":"June 2004"},{"v":0.0,"f":"0"}, {"v":0.0,"f":"0"}]},
               {"c":[{"v":new Date(2004,8,1),"f":"September 2004"},{"v":0.0,"f":"0"},{"v":0.0,"f":"0"}]},
               {"c":[{"v":new Date(2013,9,1),"f":"October 2013"},{"v":1.0,"f":"1"},{"v":83.0,"f":"83"}]}]
    }
 }
```

It will return row and cols on search query if i search two individual word the the result is like above JSON. nay idea to how can i can make class Trend.java and that list object that holds all this informations

Answer (score 0):

How would you represent those values? I'd go for a `List<HashMap<String, String>>` implementation.

You can assign each item in a row to a `HashMap` with the column header as the `key`. So:

```
HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
row.put("id", "c");
// add the rest.
```

Then you can cycle through each row, and request the column data by name. This will also make for some very semantically nice code!

Comment: cols values are dynamic it's 3 for now it may be 2 or 4 also based on search.                                                                                
and i want to store all this list or maps in one java class object

Comment: Well you can wrap up this `List` inside a class `Trend`. As for the dynamic columns, the `HashMap` can store as many columns as you want. The solution fits. All you have to do is figure out how to cycle through the `JSON` values.